# Python : Cannot find any functions within my own module?

Tags: python, python-2.7, module, attributes, webapp2

I have created my own module with filename `mymodule.py`. The file contains:

```
def testmod():
       print "test module success"
```

I have placed this file within `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mymodule/mymodule.py`

I have also added a `__init__.py` file, these have compiled to generate

`__init__.pyc` and `mymodule.pyc`

Then in the python console I import it

`import mymodule`

which works fine

when I try to use mymodule.testmod() I get the following error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'testmod'`

So yeah it seems like it has no functions?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a *package* `mymodule`, containing a *module* `mymodule`. The function is part of the module, not the package.

Import the module:

```
import mymodule.mymodule
```

and reference the function on that:

```
mymodule.mymodule.testmod()
```

You can use `from ... import` and `import ... as` to influence what gets imported exactly:

```
from mymodule import mymodule

mymodule.testmod()
```

or

```
from mymodule import mymodule as nestedmodule

nestedmodule.testmod
```

or

```
from mymodule.mymodule import testmod

testmod()
```

etc.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem and another issue I was having :) **+1**

Comment: Very Clear. Great!